# Build C program in gcc and run it in valgrind using Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am studying programming, which requires me to write and run many small programs, so I cannot make a makefile for each one. I want to make a command that would take current open file, compile it with gcc (with arguments) and run it with valgrind (with arguments as well), while allowing me to interact with it (possible by opening another shell window). Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. You want to compile the program with custom arguments, and run it with Valgrind using custom arguments, but you won't write a Makefile for it? It takes about 5 seconds longer to save those commands in a Makefile than it takes to type them once. If you type them even twice you're in a hole. Why wouldn't you write a Makefile?

Comment: @Chris sorry, I meant that both gcc and valgrind have their arguments, not that they are unique for every program.

Comment: Then I understand even less. Write your Makefile once and copy it.

Comment: @Chris I just want it to work in style of "compile this file and run it with these parameters". My current workflow is bash script and regular text editor, and I want to launch this bash script directly from text editor.

Comment: Do you mean a bash script doing what a Makefile traditionally would? That is, the bash script takes care of compiling your file?

Comment: @Chris I mean integrate this bash script into any editor, so it would compile and launch the program in one click

Comment: I'll ask again: what does the bash script _do_? They can do just about anything. What does it mean to "integrate [it] into any editor"? Simply to execute it from the editor? Does it need any arguments? Does it need to be executed from a particular directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your compile-command in the buffer by writing

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -o foo foo.c && valgrind foo" -*-
```

in the first line.

You may want to do `(put 'compile-command 'safe-local-variable 'stringp)` to prevent Emacs from warning you about the file local variable (but realize that untrusted files can potentially do malicious things).

I have a yasnippet snippet for adding this to one-off files.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: compile
# key: compile
# expand-env: ((file (if (buffer-file-name) (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) (buffer-name))))
# --
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -DDEBUG=9 -ansi -Wall -g3 -std=c99 -o ${1:$(file-name-sans-extension yas-text)} ${1:`file`}" -*-
```

Comment: What will happen when valgrind runs the program? Will it be in a separate buffer?

Comment: All output goes to the same buffer.

Answer (score 2):

> I am studying programming, which requires me to write and run many small programs, so I cannot make a makefile for each one.

As I mentioned in a comment I don't understand this logic, but if you insist on typing the commands each time you could run `M-x compile` and change the command to whatever you want (e.g. `gcc -Wall --foo file.c` or `valgrind myapp arg1 arg2`), then hit `RET`.

The next time you run `M-x compile` in the same Emacs session it will suggest the previous command. This should hopefully save you a few keystrokes.